# How to compare almost similar Strings in Java? (String distance measure)

Tags: java, string, comparison, levenshtein-distance, string-metric

I would like to compare two strings and get some score how much these look alike.
For example *"The sentence is almost similar"* and *"The sentence is similar"*.

I'm not familiar with existing methods in Java, but for PHP I know the [levenshtein function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php).

Are there better methods in Java?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? Pronounced similar? Is visually similar?

Comment: @Astor, judging from the example I'd say that neither visual nor pronunciation similarity are the wanted measure here.

Comment: This is a good example of a "good question", but folks who desire to close all kind of questions on stackoverflow ... the question is clear. Why then close it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Levensthein distance *is* a measure for how similar strings are. Or, more precisely, how many alterations have to be made that they are the same.

The [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance) is available in pseudo-code on Wikipedia. Converting that to Java shouldn't be much of a problem, but it's not built-in into the base class library.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures) has some more algorithms that measure similarity of strings.

Answer (score 59):

The following Java libraries offer multiple compare algorithms (Levenshtein,Jaro Winkler,...):

1. **Apache Commons Lang 3**: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/
2. **Simmetrics**: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/

Both libraries have a java documentation ([Apache Commons Lang Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29),[Simmetrics Javadoc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/files/simmetrics_javadocs/)).

```
//Usage of Apache Commons Lang 3
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;   
public double compareStrings(String stringA, String stringB) {
    return StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(stringA, stringB);
}

 //Usage of Simmetrics
import uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics.similaritymetrics.JaroWinkler    
public double compareStrings(String stringA, String stringB) {
    JaroWinkler algorithm = new JaroWinkler();
    return algorithm.getSimilarity(stringA, stringB);
}
```

Comment: super lib, easy to use and good results

Comment: Its available in Apache commons-lang now: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getJaroWinklerDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: A library based on this is now on GitHub https://github.com/Simmetrics/simmetrics. It is also available on Maven Central

Answer (score 16):

yeah thats a good metric, you could use [StringUtil.getLevenshteinDistance()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from apache commons

Comment: It is not available in Java Mobile Edition, is it? But thanks for your response!

Comment: you can use it with ME, just add the jar.

Comment: hmmm, no, I'm not really so sure it's completely usable with J2ME, it has been compiled with a J2SE

Comment: it doesn't use anything ME doesn't support. you can make and copy in the jar

Answer (score 3):

You can find implementations of Levenshtein and other string similarity/distance measures on
https://github.com/tdebatty/java-string-similarity

If your project uses maven, installation is as simple as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.debatty</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-string-similarity</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, to use Levenshtein for example

```
import info.debatty.java.stringsimilarity.*;

public class MyApp {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Levenshtein l = new Levenshtein();

    System.out.println(l.distance("My string", "My $tring"));
    System.out.println(l.distance("My string", "My $tring"));
    System.out.println(l.distance("My string", "My $tring"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug, but I wrote a library also:

https://github.com/vickumar1981/stringdistance

It has all these functions, plus a few for phonetic similarity (if one word "sounds like" another word - returns either true or false unlike the other fuzzy similarities which are numbers between 0-1).

Also includes dna sequencing algorithms like Smith-Waterman and Needleman-Wunsch which are generalized versions of Levenshtein.

I plan, in the near future, on making this work with any array and not just strings (an array of characters).