# Are there any libraries in android for identifying phonetically same sound

Tags: android, search

I am trying to build an android application. 
In one of the screens the user can type something in a search bar and I have to take same action for different spellings of the same word.

**For eg:** User can type *"elephant"* or *"alephant"* or *"elefant"*. I have to take same action for all these three words.

Is there any library that identifies these words as similar ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double Metaphone and Metaphone3 are excellent solutions to identify phonetically similar words.
I used Double Metaphone in my case, simply because it is open source and the java implementation is available. It works very well.

[Java implementation for Metaphone & Double Metaphone](http://commons.apache.org/codec/userguide.html)

Metaphone 3 is supposedly better but I don't think there is free [implementation](http://amorphics.com/) available

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use sound ex to get some phonetic distance between strings : [The most efficient way to implement a phonetic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359595/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-a-phonetic-search)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the spell checker could : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

That's a different approach but quite close and more flexible.

Comment: Thank you . This would be of great help in english. But I have to identify similar sounding words in other languages like hindi etc.

Comment: phonetic is quite language dependent actually. There won't be anything like a general solution that can be applied to hindi, english and french.