# Match string with normal characters and special characters in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to find a way to match user search queries with a database records in a search engine, using Spring, but I'm having trouble when the search query includes special characters such as vowels with accent.

Eg: search query = 'cafe'. Database record = 'café'

I'm using the stem of words to the query with the database records.

Which would be the most straight forward way of matching the query including a special character 'café' with the string that doesn't contain this special character 'cafe' and viceversa?

UPDATE

All the information I need is already cached so the approach of creating a new column in the db is not so appealing. I'm looking for a solution more spring based.

Comment: not sure which DB you are using but mysql support regex. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: What "search engine"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359595/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-a-phonetic-search
Please check

Answer (score 5):

You could use `java.text.Normalizer`, like follow:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;

public static String removeAccents(String text) {
    return text == null ? null :
        Normalizer.normalize(text, Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

The `Normalizer` splits the original characters into a set of two character (letter and accent).
For example the character `á` (U+00E1) will be split in `a` (U+0061) and `acute accent` U+0301

The `\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+` regular expression will match all such diacritic codes and we will replace them with an empty string.

And your `query` could be like:

SQL SERVER

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Column Like '%stringwithoutaccents%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

ORACLE (from 10g)

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE  NLSSORT(Column, 'NLS_SORT = Latin_AI')
Like NLSSORT('%stringwithoutaccents%', 'NLS_SORT = Latin_AI')
```

The CI stands for "Case Insensitive" and AI for "Accent Insensitive".

I hope it helps you.