# How can I measure the distance between two words in Java?

Tags: java

Very straightforward question: how can I measure the distance between two words in a text in Java? For example, the text could be:

The **color** of the car is **blue**.

How can I get the distance of the word **color** and **blue** in this sentence? I know that the distance from **color** to **blue** is 5. How can I get this distance of 5 in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what basis are you saying that the distance between color and blue is 5? It is either 4 or 15. Nevertheless, where is the code you've attempted and what doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: No, the distance is 5, but the way he's asking is weird

Comment: You could do some research before - possible duplicate of [How to compare almost similar Strings in Java? (String distance measure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084730/how-to-compare-almost-similar-strings-in-java-string-distance-measure)

Comment: Split the sentence by empty space and work with indexes to find out the so called distance.

Comment: @R.J yes , and when there is zero word between two words, the distance between them is 1.

Comment: @Fabinout That's weird.. but you can add 1 to the final result according to my solution.

Comment: @R.J That's not weird that's how distance has always been calculated. 'a' and 'b' are 1unit of distance appart in the alphabet, etc.

Comment: @Fabinout the way I am asking is not weird. I am simply asking about the distance between two word entities in a corpus. What is so weird about that? You saying its weird makes you weird.

Comment: "you're the weirdo", "no you're the weirdo". Reddit all the way down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be an approximation to the solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String strWords = "The color of the car is blue.";
    final String word1 = "color";
    final String word2 = "blue";

    // Remove any special chars from string
    final String strOnlyWords = strWords.replace(",", "").replace(".", "");

    final List<String> words = Arrays.asList(strOnlyWords.split(" "));
    final int index1 = words.indexOf(word1);
    final int index2 = words.indexOf(word2);
    int distance = -1;

    // Check index of two words
    if (index1 != -1 && index2 != - 1) {
        distance = index2 - index1;
    }

    System.out.println(distance);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you can do:

1. [Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the array according to whitespaces.
2. Get the index of the *first word*.
3. Get the index of the *second word*.
4. Subtract the indexes, that's the "distance".

Translating this to Java is straightforward.. I leave it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following code:

```
    String s = "The color of the car is blue";
    String[] arr = s.split(" ");
    int startIndex = -1;
    int endIndex = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].equals("color")){
            startIndex = i;
        }
        else if(arr[i].equals("blue")){
            endIndex = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("distance is: " + (endIndex-startIndex));
```

Comment: Spoon feeding an answer to the OP(specially when there is no effort shown) is discouraged here.

Comment: @R.J He is giving the OP a concrete & specific answer. The OP if they want to use it for anything (hint, their homework) will have to generalize it, wrap it in a method, and perhaps optimize it (the given answer is O(n) but you can have it be O(1) if one doesn't count preprocessing).

Comment: @John - How difficult would it be to put this code in a method? Ahh, see another answer below, within a method now. That's exactly why such a practice is discouraged when there is absolutely no effort shown by the OP.

Comment: @R.J I think code example helps for novice users

Comment: @Meet - Trust me. This may help them this time, but later on, they're going to struggle a lot. And it will only encourage them to ask more such questions, which is neither good for the OP or the community.

Comment: If you've sometime, read this [open letter to the students](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166) and a few answers posted for it. It might help you understand a bit more of what I'm trying to say here.

Comment: @R.J You may find this interesting: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html . It eludes to the "struggle later" you point to, and parallels part of what you linked to.

Comment: The question was not clear. My bad, I will make a new one..