# Set Selected Item JComboBox from String

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` that have values build from two parts **int-String** like this:

```
01-one
02-two
03-three
```

So now I have just the `String` part, and want to `setSelectedItem` the item with this part, but i think this is not possible, because the values is not matching or not same

```
myComboBox.setSelectedItem("?" + myString);
```

So what i want to do is :

```
myComboBox.setSelectedItem("like myString");
```

Someone have an idea to set select the item that is LIKE the value in combobox or this is not possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible -- you will have to create a method that checks if one String is *similar enough* to another String, and perhaps returns either a numeric value or true, and use that to figure out which index to set the selected item to.

Comment: mmm, i really don't think for this solution, thank you @HovercraftFullOfEels this can help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare almost similar Strings in Java? (String distance measure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084730/how-to-compare-almost-similar-strings-in-java-string-distance-measure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the `.contains` method where you see whether the first item in the combo box contains that specific word and repeat it until you find the specific index.

For example:

```
if (jComboBox1.getItemAt(0).toString ().contains ("two")) 
{ 
    jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

And repeat the step or try using a for loop, it's great if your combo box contains many items.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to select exactly by the string, which is what you indicate in the description, I would create a class to represent your specific item, maintaining in it the int and string as separate fields, and override `toString()` to return the representation you want. You can then have a method searching your item based on the string alone. For a relatively small number of items, this is efficient and simple. If you had a large number of items, I'd suggest storing them as values in a `HashMap` using the string as a key.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class Item {
  int intValue;
  String strValue;

  public Item(int intValue, String strValue) {
    this.intValue = intValue;
    this.strValue = strValue;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return intValue + " - " + strValue;
  }
}

public class TestCombo {
  private static JComboBox<Item> cb;
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(640,400);
    cb = new JComboBox<>();
    cb.addItem(new Item(1, "one"));
    cb.addItem(new Item(2, "two"));
    cb.addItem(new Item(3, "three"));
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.getContentPane().add(cb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f.setVisible(true);

    selectItemByString("three");
  }

  private static void selectItemByString(String s) {
    for (int i=0; i<cb.getItemCount(); i++) {
      if (cb.getItemAt(i).strValue.equals(s)) {
        cb.setSelectedIndex(i);
        break;
      }
    }
    return;
  }
}
```